# whereNotIn is not working or my code is wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Currently, I'm adding items into a price list, however it should not let add the same item twice, or specifically the same ID. **Articulo** model has the ID that **listas_precios_articulos** model has as articulo_id.

I used whereNotIn clause to achieve that but it is not working. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks!

```
public function findArticulo(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    $articulos = Articulo::query()->select([
        'id',
        'codigo_interno',
        'codigo_comercial',
        'impuestos_venta',
        'impuestos_compra',
        'nombre',
        'descripcion',
        'status'])
        ->where('status','activo')->whereNotIn('id', function($query)use($id){
        $query->select('articulo_id')
            ->from('listas_precios_articulos')
            ->where('lista_precio_id', $id)
            ->whereNotIn('estatus', ['eliminado']);
    })
        ->where('nombre', 'like', "%".$request->nombre."%")
        ->Orwhere('codigo_interno', 'like', "%".$request->nombre."%")
        ->Orwhere('codigo_comercial' , 'like' , "%".$request->nombre."%")
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

    return response()->json($articulos,200);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this query must return an array to make it correct in whereNotIn statement

```
$query->select('articulo_id')
            ->from('listas_precios_articulos')
            ->where('lista_precio_id', $id)
            ->whereNotIn('estatus', ['eliminado'])
            ->toArray();
```

and maybe this was a typo error ->Orwhere...must be ->orWhere

UPDATED
could you split the query and do this:

```
$id = $request->id;
$pluckedIds = ListasPreciosArticulo::
              where('lista_precio_id', $id)
            ->where('estatus','!=','eliminado')
            ->pluck('id');

$articulos = Articulo::query()->select([
        'id',
        'codigo_interno',
        'codigo_comercial',
        'impuestos_venta',
        'impuestos_compra',
        'nombre',
        'descripcion',
        'status'])
->where('status','activo')->whereNotIn('id', [$pluckedIds])
->where('nombre', 'like', "%".$request->nombre."%")
        ->orWhere('codigo_interno', 'like', "%".$request->nombre."%")
        ->orWhere('codigo_comercial' , 'like' , "%".$request->nombre."%")
        ->get();

return response()->json($articulos,200);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However still lets me add duplicate items :( I tried to add a get() befor the toArray and still no luck.